# How do I detect my computer's RAM configuration?

Tags: windows-7, memory

Is there any way I can detect how the memory in my computer is distributed short of opening the side of the machine and taking a look? I thought there was a way to do this from the Control Panel, but I don't remember how.

For example, my Dell Inspiron PC running Windows 7 reports that it has 2GB of RAM installed. Do I have one 2GB stick or two 1GB sticks?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are several utilities that can provide that information. For instance:

- [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html)
- [BlackBox](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/hwm_blackbox.html)
- [HWInfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/)

You can also use WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) to find that information without any third-party utilities. Just run the following in a command prompt:

```
wmic MemoryChip get BankLabel, Capacity, DeviceLocator
```

You can also run `wmic MemoryChip` to show everything Windows knows about your memory modules.

Comment: So there are ways to do this with third-party software, but nothing prepackaged in Windows to view this sort of information? That seems odd to me, I really thought there was some way to see it in the Device Manager or something. Ah, well.

Comment: @Andrew Actually there is a way, using WMI. I've edited my answer to provide instructions.

Answer (score 9):

I have always used the crucial system scanner at http://www.crucial.com/
It can provide for you the configuration and type of RAM you have installed.

Answer (score 3):

One Windows 8 upwards...

1. Windows Task Manager
2. Performance tab
3. Memory

Will give you easy access to a certain amount of info including what the OP asked for:

[image]

[image]